# jQuery build a form that submits w/o causing the browser to resubmit on back

Tags: jquery

When you visit google.com and submit a search query. The form does not post but somehow the q param ends up in the URL allowing google to know what you're searching for. What's nice about this is that if you go back the browser doesn't ask if you want to repost.

What's a good way with jQuery to build a form that does just that. On submit, it gets with the form input as a url param, and doesn't trigger the browser back btn?

Thanks

Comment: ...cuz Google's using GET requests, not POST.

Comment: @Thomas, right! How do I build a jquery form that on submit does a get?

Comment: @TheExit. Change the method attribute on the form tag from POST to GET.

Comment: @Craig put that in an answer. Obvious and simple.

Comment: Question could use improvement. Do you want to do an request without a page reload, change the current URL, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parent.location.hash` to achieve the effect you desire. For example, create a button with the following code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="parent.location.hash='Your+URL+parameters'" />
```

When you click the button, "#Your+URL+parameters" will be appended to the URL in the browser's address bar.

Comment: Not sure what this is all about?

Comment: Go ahead and give it a try. If you use parent.location.hash, the value you provide will be appended to the current URL. This is how Google achieves the effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the hash tag "#myparams", go with George's answer. 
If you want a "form" that when submitted does a get request, you don't need a form. You just need some inputs and a button or link that redirects to your location with the input values passed in: `<a href="mypage.php?mmyvalue=epicvalue&myotherval=myepicval2">`

See a full example with jQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/KAtyq/7/

Answer (score 1):

Change the method attribute on the form tag from POST to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax.
Something like:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   //some ajax fn
})
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mCbaY/

Or a real example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3mAbh/show/

Type in `26UNk` and one of my other fiddles will load (after alert) (this example only loads my fiddles, so try loading any of my fiddle ids and it will load)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to integrate with Google. I want my search form to post as a url with a Q param and not cause the browser to error with a do you want to resubmit dialog when going back.

Comment: @TheExit, i was just posting the google thing as an example of an ajax call, you can use anything instead of it